# Connecting to Team Foundation Server (TFS) with proxy authentication

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, codeplex

Yesterday I created a new project in Codeplex. I created a connection from Visual Studio to the TFS server I was assigned and uploaded my solution successfully. Today I'm trying to connect again to the Codeplex TFS server to work on the solution. When I try to open it, I get the error:

> Team Foundation Server
>   https://tfs06.codeplex.com/ does not
>   exist or is not accessible at this
>   time.
>
> The remote server returned an error:
>   (407) Proxy Authentication Required.

The corporate environment I'm using does use proxy authentication but this wasn't an issue yesterday. Any ideas on why it worked then and how to make it work now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visiting the Start Page (under View, Other Windows, Start Page) as recommended by [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005955/connecting-to-team-foundation-server-tfs-with-proxy-authentication/1006053#1006053) seems to reset the proxy authentication in some way.

An authentication prompt will then appear by going to Tools, Connect to Team Foundation Server, and selecting the server from the dropdown. Going to File, Source Control, Go Online then reconnects the solution.

Comment: If you don't visit the start page, the solution may not go back online. Instead you'll get the Proxy auth 407 error again.

Answer (score 5):

Do you want to try refreshing the start page in Visual Studio (View, Other Windows, Start Page)?  Sounds bizarre but the following forum post suggest that this might work...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfssetup/thread/c46afd34-09ea-4505-a34e-b378cb35138d

Comment: Saw that but I have the Start Page turned off. Hmmm... maybe this is why!

Comment: Possibly - sounds like there is a bug with proxy auth stuff.  I'll check to see if it has been fixed.

Comment: This also means that one cannot connect using MS Excel

Comment: This is not affecting VS 2010. have them installed side-by-side with Start page in both IDEs turned on, and its only happening in VS 2008.

Comment: @AnonymousType It's very likely I was experiencing this problem in VS2008. Unfortunately I didn't put that detail in the question!

Comment: Yes I understand. This problem actually came back interestingly for the user(dev) even after I removed the config option for start page from Tools>Options. I ended up removing one of the SSAS projects because it had circular brackets in the project name - which was causing a Invalid file path error on checkout.

Comment: @MartinWoodward This 407 issue still happens with VS2013.2. The "Start Page" workaround helps though. Thanks for this <3. FWIW, this uservoice entry specifically deals with this: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3608445-make-visual-studio-or-the-tfs-plugin-ask-credent