# Proxy authentication error when connecting to Codeplex with Team Explorer

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

Similarly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005955/connecting-to-team-foundation-server-tfs-with-proxy-authentication) I have a project on Codeplex and when I attempt to connect to the Codeplex TFS server in Visual Studio 2012 (on windows 8) I get a 407 'proxy authentication' server error.

My company does use a proxy server but I could previously connect to the Codeplex TFS server  with Visual Studio 2010 on windows 7.

I have tried refreshing the start page as suggested in the linked question but this has no effect. Are there any other options to get connected to TFS?

To duplicate run VS2012 Premium in W8 click Team > Connect to Team Foundation Server, Click 'Servers...' then 'Add...', enter 'https://tfs.codeplex.com:443/tfs/TFS03' in the first textbox then click OK. Error TF31002 popup appears.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same issue with VS2012 under Windows 7 to connect to my codeplex project. Going to Visual Studio start page, or into the extension manager to help set up the proxy authentication did not help.

Actually the proxy authentication has been turned on one day without notice from our admins, grrrr.

I solved the problem by going into my **Windows "Vault" => Manage Windows Credentials**, and **removed every credential entry related to codeplex**. Then I removed the TFS server and registered it again in Visual Studio.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unluckily for me my Windows 8 box is locked down by a group policy so that I have no access to the Credentials Manager...